# AWS DynamoDDB + python: throughput is not being reached, how can I speed up?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a python script that performs the following operations. It reads a text file line by line. Info about each line has to be recorded in a DynamoDDB table. I process each ingested line and then perform one write like this:

```
with open(fPath, 'r') as f:
   for line in f:
      # process line, extract data to be written into DDB into item_data
      # also extract key
      item = table.new_item(hash_key=key_from_line,attrs=item_data)
      item.put()
```

I have noticed that the effective throughput, i.e. the number of writes I make per second (on average) is much lower than the max throughput I set for the table on the AWS DDB console. Now, it's possible that there are major inefficiencies at the line processing step. But I am wondering if I can also speed things up by writing into the table differently. For instance, does it make sense to collect an array of items and then write them all at once? If so, is there a way to determine the optimal size of the array? Any other simple (and maybe not so simple ways) of making writing faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you are not getting the maximum throughput is that you are creating "hot zones". That is you have too many calls to the same partition of your Table.

The fastest fix is to reverse your keys or to hash them, as they are probably having the same prefix.

Provisioned throughput is dependent on the primary key selection, and the workload patterns on individual items. When storing data, Amazon DynamoDB divides a table's items into multiple partitions, and distributes the data primarily based on the hash key element. The provisioned throughput associated with a table is also divided evenly among the partitions, with no sharing of provisioned throughput across partitions.

> Total provisioned throughput/partitions = throughput per partition.

Consequently, to achieve the full amount of request throughput you have provisioned for a table, keep your workload spread evenly across the hash key values. Distributing requests across hash key values distributes the requests across partitions.

You can see more information here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.DataUpload

Comment: And do you think that replacing `putItem()` with `boto.dynamodb.batch.BatchWrite()` might speed things up?

Comment: BatchWrite might speed things up a little, if some of the delay is on the client side. You can also check if you are repeating your UUIDs between the lines. For large attributes you can compress them with GZIP or LZO, getting another small boost to performance.